# Android resize View not smooth

Tags: android, resize

I have a custom `ImageView` and a `Button`, clicking the `Button` and moving up and down resizes the `ImageView` but it does not run smoothly.

I created a separate thread to smoothen the user movement but apparently it can't make any GUI changes.. I tried to find a way to use `Animation` but i don't see a way to continuously update the target height.

Working code
Button onTouchListener:

```java
// resize button start location
private PointF startResize = new PointF();

    ImageView resize = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.resize );
    resize.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    // save first touch location
                    startResize.set( boardImage.getHeight(), event.getY() );
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    // calculate horizontal move distance
                    int movedDistance = Math.round(event.getY() - startResize.y);

                    if ( Math.abs( movedDistance ) > 4 ) {

                        // set new height
                        boardImage.setHeight( movedDistance + (int)startResize.x );
                    }

                    break;
            }
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }
    });
```

Custom ImageView
setHeight:

```java
// set height and revalidate
public void setHeight( int newHeight ){

    height = newHeight;

    // rescale image
    setImageMatrix( checkMatrix() );

    requestLayout();
}
```

onMeasure:

```java
@Override
public void onMeasure( int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec ) {

    setMeasuredDimension( width, height );
}
```

***EDIT*** better explanation

Touching the red encircled `Button` and dragging it up/down resizes the `ImageView` above it to any given size. see images below.

I tried to use an `Animation` but i have to cancel it and set a new one with every tiny little movement made witch results in creating 20/30 new Animations every second..

[image: zoomed layout]
<sub>(source: [eightytwo.axc.nl](http://roelept82.eightytwo.axc.nl/pic/link1.png))</sub>

[image: layout]
<sub>(source: [eightytwo.axc.nl](http://roelept82.eightytwo.axc.nl/pic/link2.png))</sub>